# How to hide the comments counter in a Google Sheets tab?

Tags: google-sheets

On every sheet that has comments in it, Google Sheets shows the total number of comments in a green box in the tab at the bottom of the screen:

[image: Google Sheets tab]

Is there any way to hide it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my knowledge, there is no way to hide this comment counter.
However, be aware the flag will only count open comments and not total comments on the tab.
This means if you resolve open comments in the Sheet, you will notice the counter going down and eventually disappearing when there are no more comments left.

You can see all comments on a sheet by right-clicking on the tab and selecting "View Comments". You can also cycle through all comments on the sheet/tab by using Ctrl + ALT + N to go to the next comment, or Ctrl + ALT + P to go the the previous comment.
Finally, you can navigate through the comments via Comment History.

This way you should be able to eventually find and resolve all open comments as a workaround to get rid of the counter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sometimes I'm using comments as notes for myself, not as todos or error flags.

Comment: Cells have an actual notes functionality that you could use. If you right click on the cell there is an option to set note and clear note. Personally I find it clunky and hence prefer comments too, but it would allow you to set as many notes as you want without showing the flag. :)

You can mark my answer to make your question show as solved. Unless you want to wait for somebody to find a non-conventional solution (script, extension etc).

Comment: Holy moly, I completely missed the "Insert note" dropdown option. Cheers.